# In-Memory Data Grid for Java Project

Tags: caching, datagrid, scalability, distributed

I'm looking to use an in memory data grid for my java project. I know there are a few relevant products such as VMWare GemFire, GigaSpaces XAP, IBM eXtreme Scale and others. Can someone elaborate from their experience with any of these tools and how they compare to one another? Thanks, Alex

Comment: You could also add TayzGrid as a [java data grid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/)

Answer (score 5):

(disclaimer - I work for GigaSpaces)

Hi Alex

There are many criteria to compare by, it really depends on what you're trying to do. in memory data grid have a lot of use cases, e.g. caching, OLTP, high throughput event processing, etc. 
In general, the main criteria you should be looking at are:

- Programming model: Support popular Java frameworks such as Spring (XAP and Gemfire support it natively)
- Querying and indexing: if you want more than trivial key/value data access. Most people need SQL like semantics, or even full text search, and if the data grid can provide that out of the box it's a big advantage.
- Ability to execute code on the grid nodes, and even colocate your code with them and handle events that are injected to the grid (e.g. objects written or updated). This is a massive scalability benefit and allows you to implement very efficient shared-nothing architectures.
- Languages and APIs support: Most data grid support at least Java and JVM based languages (e.g. Scala), but a lot of them also support other languages and allow you to access the same data from various programming languages. For example XAP supports natively Java, .Net and C++, and other languages using its REST and memcached interfaces. As far as APIs go, some grid support more than one API. At GigaSpaces we support Map, Spring/POJO, JPA, JDBC and others.
- Transactions: This is also a big one if you want to go anywhere beyond caching. When using the memory as your system of record, you should be able to rollback state in case you have an error or a bug, otherwise you end up with corrupt data. Another important thing is what types of transactions are supported. A lot of data grids only support "local" transactions. i.e. within the boundaries of a single node / partition / shard (which is probably what you want to do in most cases for performance reason). But more advanced grids also support distributed transactions and know how to seamlessly upgrade from local to distributed when needed.
- Replication: there are various models here (synchronous, asynchronous, hybrid) and you need to decide which one of them is best for your use case. Some grids also have explicit support for cross cluster replication over WAN which is important if you're implementing DR.
- Data partitioning and scalability: how does the grid partition data (fixed / consistent hashing), what is the level of control the user has over it, and does it support dynamic addition of server to the grid to increase capacity.
- Administration and monitoring: Last but not least - what kind of facilities are provided out of the box, such as monitoring and administration hooks (JMX or another administrative API), user interfaces and integration with other 3rd party systems.

The following links are a good place to start:

1. http://gojko.net/2009/06/01/oracle-coherence-vs-gigaspaces-xap/. Also read the comments
2. http://www.neovise.com/neovise-data-caching-performance-technical-white-paper - a recent comparison between GigaSpaces and GemFire which I think speaks for itself :)

HTH, 
Uri

Answer (score 0):

There's a summary of the In-Memory Data Grid market by Gartner called "Competitive Landscape: In-Memory Data Grids". You can see a copy at: http://www.gartner.com/technology/reprints.do?id=1-1HCCIMJ&ct=130718&st=sb

Oracle Coherence (previously Tangosol Coherence) is and has long been the market leader in this space, but it is a commercial product. As I explained elsewhere recently:

Pros:

- Elastic. Just add nodes. Auto-discovery. Auto-load-balancing. No data loss. No interruption. Every time you add a node, you get more data capacity and more throughput.
- Use both RAM and flash. Transparently. Easily handle 10s or even 100s of gigabytes per Coherence node (e.g. up to a TB or more per physical server).
- Automatic high availability (HA). Kill a process, no data loss. Kill a server, no data loss.
- Datacenter continuous availability (CA). Kill a data center, no data loss.
- RESTful APIs available from any language. Native APIs and client libraries for C/C++, C#, .NET and Java.
- In addition to simple key-value (K/V) caching, also support queries (including some SQL), parallel queries, indexes (including custom indexes), a rich eventing model (for event-driven systems like exchanges), transactions (including MVCC), parallel execution of both scalar (EntryProcessor) and aggregate (ParallelAwareAggregator) functions, cache triggers, etc.
- Easy to integrate with a database via read-through, read-ahead, write-through and write-behind caching. Automatically refreshes just the changed data when changes occur to the database (leveraging Oracle GoldenGate technology).
- Coherence Incubator: The Coherence Incubator
- memcache protocol support: Memcached interface for Oracle Coherence project on github
- Thousands of customers, some using Coherence in production now for over a decade.

Cons:

- As of Coherence 12.1.2, the cache itself is not persistent.
- It costs money.

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the  opinions or views of my employer.*